# x0vncserver unable to open display :0

Tags: server, display, vnc

I am attempting to use `x0vncserver` from the package `tigervnc-scraping-server` to run a VNC server using my local desktop session. Many guides such as [this](https://www.howtoforge.com/tutorial/how-to-start-a-vnc-server-for-the-actual-display-scraping-with-tigervnc/) recommend starting the server with

```
x0vncserver -passwordfile ~/.vnc/passwd -display :0
```

or

```
x0vncserver -display :0
```

For me, both result in

```
No protocol specified
x0vncserver: unable to open display ":0"
```

How can I fix this? I have seen similar issues where the desktop session is owned by a different user, but I am the only user in this situation.

Comment: So are you actually running an X server on :0? what does `pgrep -a Xorg` return for example?

Comment: I believe so? I am running Gnome. I thought the idea was that `x0vncserver` uses your active desktop session. The output of the command you gave is:

```1454 /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg vt1 -displayfd 3 -auth /run/user/125/gdm/Xauthority -background none -noreset -keeptty -verbose 3
2440 /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg vt2 -displayfd 3 -auth /run/user/1000/gdm/Xauthority -background none -noreset -keeptty -verbose 3```

Comment: Apologies - that command wasn't as helpful as I'd hoped, since apparently newer Xorg sessions don't show the display number directly on the command line any more. If you open a terminal emulator in your local desktop session does `echo $DISPLAY` return `:0` or something else? Sometimes the primary display is :1

Comment: No problem -- thank *you* for your help! `echo $DISPLAY` returns nothing. Extra context if relevant: I am SSHing into my machine which is powered on at home and connected to a monitor, presumably with a locked screen.

Comment: Ah that's unfortunate - that's why I specifically mentioned *"a terminal emulator in your local desktop session"*. If you're trying to get the information via SSH then it is more complicated - see for example [How to find out the current (active) XServer DISPLAY number?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/204498/65304)

Comment: ... actually `xauth list` might be helpful

Comment: `xauth list` returns:

`redacted.local:2  MIT-MAGIC-COOKIE-1  redacted_alphanumeric_string`\n

`redacted/unix:2  MIT-MAGIC-COOKIE-1  redacted_alphanumeric_string`\n

`redacted.local:3  MIT-MAGIC-COOKIE-1  redacted_alphanumeric_string`\n

`redacted/unix:3  MIT-MAGIC-COOKIE-1  redacted_alphanumeric_string`

Comment: OK so it looks like X servers are / have been running on displays :2 and :3

Comment: Ah, these are from my normal tigervnc sessions. I am also trying to use x0vncserver so I can run a vnc session with my local desktop rather than creating a new desktop environment like tigervnc does.

Comment: Interestingly, those vnc servers were killed prior to me running `xauth list`...

Comment: That's normal - that's why I said `/ have been`. I still have xauth entries on my box for a server that's been offline since before the pandemic ... . Are you sure your local desktop is actually an X session (not a Wayland session for example)? Apologies if I asked that before, I don't remember what we already covered

Comment: Ah -- no I am not sure. I am running Ubuntu 20.04 on GNOME. Sorry, I'm coming over from being a Mac guy. I just assumed all the GUI stuff was X.